# Uploading a C String using libcurl

Tags: c, curl, upload, libcurl

I have a char array that stores 250KB of data. I'd like to upload this char array to my bucket on S3 using libcurl. I know how to upload a file and I can write all the data to a file and send the file to the S3, but that'd add an unnecessary extra step.

Long story short, how can I upload a specific part of memory using libcurl?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The code is ready if it had been a file, but it is irrelevant to this question, since what I want is to send the memory chunk directly without a file pointer.

Comment: So instead of `upload_this_file(FILE *fp, char *URL)`, you want `upload_this_data(char *data, size_t len, char *URL)`?

Comment: libcurl makes this very easy, like this example shows https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postinmemory.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution and successfully uploaded data without using a intermediate file.

If you don't declare a read callback function, libcurl uses fread which requires you to enter a file pointer as an input. The way I found to overcome this pointer issue is to write a read callback function and enter the void pointer as an input to the READDATA. Without further ado, here's the working code. Another important note is the size of the frameset you'll upload.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int framesetSize = 10;
void *frameset = "0123456789";
static size_t my_read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *dummy)
{
    // we will ignore dummy, and pass frameset as a global parameter, along with framesetSize
    size_t retcode = 0;

    if  (framesetSize == 0) 
// we have already finished off all the data
        return retcode; // initialized to 0

    retcode =  ( size * nmemb >= framesetSize) ? framesetSize : size * nmemb; 
// set return code as the smaller of max allowed data and remaining data

    framesetSize -=  retcode; // adjust left amount
    memcpy(ptr, frameset, retcode);
    frameset += retcode ; // advance frameset pointer
    return retcode;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    double speed_upload, total_time;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        /* upload to this place */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, my_read_callback);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                         "54.231.19.24/{YOURBUCKETNAME}/furkan-1.txt");

        /* tell it to "upload" to the URL */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

        /* set where to read from (on Windows you need to use READFUNCTION too) */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &frameset);

        /* and give the size of the upload (optional) */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, framesetSize);

        /* enable verbose for easier tracing */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        }
        else {
            /* now extract transfer info */
            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &speed_upload);
            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &total_time);

            fprintf(stderr, "Speed: %.3f bytes/sec during %.3f seconds\n",
                    speed_upload, total_time);

        }
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```